# How can I get children elements from QueryList in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am newbie at Angular2. In my view I have few identical children that are generated in *ngFor.

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let client of clients" [title]="'Client #' + client.id">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
        <processing-item [client]="client"></processing-item>
    </template>
</ngb-panel>
```

I need to call methods of these components at parent element and find out the ViewChildren decorator and the code is:

```
@ViewChildren(ProcessingItemComponent) processingItems: QueryList<ProcessingItemComponent>;
```

Then I try to iterate them by forEach:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.processingItems.forEach(function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    });
}
```

But it does nothing. toArray() method called on QueryList returns empty array.

Any suggestions how can I get all children components at one time and call its methods?

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If `clients` is set from an async call (for example to the server) then the elements don't exist in `ngAfterViewInit()` yet.

You can use

```ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.processingItems.changes.subscribe(() => {
    this.processingItems.toArray().forEach(el => {
        console.log(el);
    });
  });
}
```

See also https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#changes

Comment: The trouble is that processingItems are not iterable somehow, but it exists. When I try to log this element I get this http://joxi.ru/Dr8OEypCkMeY0A

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `toArray()`

Comment: It doesn't metter, processingItems exists and has array of children in _result, but toArray() returns empty array :(

Comment: Even within `subscribe(...)`? Your screenshot shows 5 elements were found, `toArray()` should definitely return an array that contains these elements. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I think you means `this.processingItems.changes.subscribe(...)`. :-)

Comment: @Pengyy you are right. Thanks a lot. My memory decayed during vacation :-/

Comment: @АннаЛадыженская interesting, did you not get an error for calling `subscribe()` on `this.processingItems` directly?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, i got error that subscribe() is not a function, but I thought that maybe i've done something wrong

Comment: @АннаЛадыженская I see. Sorry for the inconvenience. I was so sure that I didn't bother checking the docs :-/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nevertheless, thank you, I would not think of Observable by myself )

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using the @ContentChildren attribute instead of the ViewChildren.

```
@ContentChildren( OptionComponent )
public Options: QueryList<OptionComponent>;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why?

Comment: Sorry stefan, what I wanted to say will not fit into a comment so I have added it as an answer below

Comment: I am assuming from the code above in the original question that the user wishes to use a template syntax and content projection.  I find in this case the ContentChildren works better and would return the items. You may also want to put the <template> as <ng-content>  possibly.

Comment: This is actually not correct for this question. In the question she is creating the components 'in-place' in the same component that the `ViewChildren` is placed. So it's not injected content from a parent component - but she wants to get a reference to the list of children created *in that component* via ngFor.

Comment: Simon_Weaver is correct, but upvoting because I had a similar issue of `.toArray()` returning empty. Gunter's solution worked, but my underlying problem was that the parent container was passing the elements and I was using ViewChildren. Switching to ContentChildren allowed me to remove the subscribe logic from Gunter's answer.